# How forward packets from network interface to another

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, forwarding

My problem is forward packets from eth2 that is my LAN to eth1 that has access to internet, to allow eth2 to access to internet, here my configuration:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.3.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.3.0
    broadcast 192.168.3.255
    gateway 192.168.3.254

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 10.101.26.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.101.0.0
    broadcast 10.101.255.255
```

iptables configuration:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

Already uncomment *net.ipv4.ip forward=1* in */etc/sysctl.conf* and write 1 in */proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward*.

If i test with a PC connected on LAN that have as gateway 10.101.26.1 I can't reach internet, so how I can solve this?

Thank you for any help!
Regards

Comment: If you have a PC behind eth1, it must be on the same subnet as eth1, and the default gateway must be eth1's IP, not eth2's IP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need some sort of masquerading statement. The reason behind this is that, currently, packets arriving from eth2 to eth1 are identified by 10.101.0.0/16 addresses. Those 10.101.0.0/16 packets then attempt to traverse the network via eth1 (192.168.3.0/24). This fails because those packets haven't yet been *masqueraded* as packets from 192.168.3.1.

A little script like this below should help. Modify as necessary:

```
#! /bin/bash

IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

WANIF='eth1'
LANIF='eth2'

# enable ip forwarding in the kernel
echo 'Enabling Kernel IP forwarding...'
/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# flush rules and delete chains
echo 'Flushing rules and deleting existing chains...'
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -X

# enable masquerading to allow LAN internet access
echo 'Enabling IP Masquerading and other rules...'
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $LANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -j ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -j ACCEPT

echo 'Done.'
```

Comment: With a usb to ethernet adapter on a sbc this made for a simple isolated network I  needed inside my LAN.  Allows machines therein to access resources on the LAN and even internet.   If the WAN is to be internet facing then you should be using a full firewall like firehol.  I made a little repo with systemd service file to make this easy to deploy, persist and turn on and off.  https://github.com/dkebler/masquerade

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I am assuming your PC is behind a router and eth1 is connected to the Internet via the router. You would have to create a static route on your router to 10.101.0.0/16 via 192.168.3.1 so that reply packets destined to said network can be forwarded to your PC.

Comment: 192.168.3.1 can reach internet, I need to forward any packets from 10.101.0.0/16 to 192.168.3.1 and vice versa.
How i can create this static rule? I've already tried with this:
> route add -net 10.101.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.3.254

Comment: @Ghilander: Create the static route on your router. It's not a firewall rule.

Comment: can you show me an example please?

Comment: @Ghilander: Create a static route that's equivalent to `route add -net 10.101.0.0/16 gw 192.168.3.1` on the router (i.e.192.168.3.254).

Comment: @Ghilander: Or just use the router's admin page. Consult the user's manual on how to add static routing entry.

Comment: I don't understand why this route add -net 10.101.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.3.254 didn't work!

Comment: @Ghilander: Just to be clear, which one is the gateway router (i.e. the router that connects directly to a modem),  192.168.3.1 or 192.168.3.254?

Comment: the 192.168.3.254

Comment: @Ghilander: then read the fourth comment from the top.

Comment: Ok, but the result is the same, now I can't access ssh to the other PC to test the connection.

Comment: @Ghilander is 192.168.3.254 a dedicated router or a general purpose computer?

Comment: Is a dedicated router

Comment: @Ghilander: do `traceroute 208.67.220.220` and `ping 208.67.220.220` from a computer on the 10.101.0.0/16 network. What do the outputs say?

Comment: traceroute:
` 1  192.168.3.254 (192.168.3.254)  0.149 ms  0.361 ms  0.345 ms
 2  10.151.158.130 (10.151.158.130)  1.317 ms  1.306 ms  1.292 ms
 3  10.3.7.105 (10.3.7.105)  2.010 ms  1.960 ms  1.944 ms
 4  10.3.12.161 (10.3.12.161)  2.418 ms  2.650 ms  2.635 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  62-101-124-94.fastres.net (62.101.124.94)  6.813 ms 62-101-124-98.fastres.net (62.101.124.98)  7.308 ms  7.023 ms
`